# Update stock quantity in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using WooCommerce for a website and need to update stock quantity for each product. I have a plugin but it's a very tedious task and takes a lot of server resources and a couple hours to complete. I currently download a .csv file manually with the sku number and quantity columns and upload it via the plugin.

**.CSV:**

```
SKU,QTY
613619,127
```

I'm trying to write a SQL query to handle this so I can streamline this process.

Here is my select statement so I can see all my data:

```
SELECT * FROM wp37_pmxi_posts pp
JOIN wp37_postmeta pm ON pp.post_id = pm.post_id
WHERE pp.unique_key = 613619
```

613619 is an example sku that I receive from my .csv file which corresponds to the unique_key.

What would the update statement be to update `_stock` key value for skus? Also, if the quantity is 0, the `_stock_status` key value should be 'out of stock'.

**Here is the output from above query:**

[image]

Once I get the update statement, I can write a simple PHP script to execute it.

I would greatly appreciate your help and thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You have to get Product id of that product then :

```
  $product = new WC_Product( $id );
  $product->set_stock($qty);
```